# How to organize development workflow with Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to introduce Apache Airflow to a medium-sized team (1-10 people). 
How people can organize their work, so they can develop, test, review, deploy and not step on each others toes?

I tried to use docker images for testing, like this one: [puckel's docker image](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow). People can write their DAGs on their own machines, submit for review, and then we could deploy it to production. The disadvantage is that docker image doesn't have access to all services the production environment has (e.g. AWS API credentials) so tests are limited to relatively simple cases, or require users to do a lot of configuration themselves. The environment is also different a little bit in terms of configuration (e.g. the dependencies have to be added by the user).

Comment: Have you found any answer?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems there are no clear best practices around this yet:

Comment: (sorry - hit enter and then couldn't edit the comment) From what I understand, the way most teams work is either:
* test in production 
* use something similar to the mentioned docker approach
* have a dedicated queue/testing resources

Comment: I also encountered a mix of the first and third approach: A production Airflow instance and production read-only data sources + a dedicated development data storage for writing data (after testing, the DAGs are switched to a production data storage for writing).

Comment: I’m also looking for answers to this. The Q&A above so far was helpful! Should we simply transform it into an answer to improve on? One additional trick we currently try out is having a shared Dev instance (less to distribute & maintain incl. connection info!) using VSCode RemoteSSH for quick DAG edit turnaround (faster that Git pushes)